# Apache Cordova, SQLite, Delete from [table] where id=? does not return

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have an Apache Cordova application that caches data that cannot be sent to a server when no communications are available, such as no 3G coverage etc.

I have some code that runs when the device comes back online. The idea of this code is to recursively ripple through that cached data and send it to the server in the background. Once sent, each row should then be deleted to prevent it from being sent again.

A cut-down and anonymised version of the code follows...

```
var app = {

    name: 'myApp',
    displayName: 'my application',

    db: null,

    initialize: function () {

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener("online", app.onDeviceOnline, false);

    },

    onDeviceOnline: function () {

        app.db.transaction(
            function (tx) {
                app.uploadCachedData(tx);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.error("'" + error.message + "' creating database transaction.");
            },
            function () {
            }

        );

    },

    onDeviceReady: function () {

        app.db = window.openDatabase(app.name, "2.2", app.displayName, 1 * 1024 * 1024);

    },

    uploadCachedData: function (tx) {

        tx.executeSql('select * from [data]', [],
            function (tx, results) {

                console.log("uploadCachedData, rows.length=" + results.rows.length);
                if (results.rows.length > 0) {

                    var item = results.rows.item(0);
                    var cachedDataId = item.id;

                    console.log("Uploading cached data, id=" + cachedDataId)
                    app.ws.uploadImage(item.f1, item.f2, item.f3, item.f4, item.f5,
                        function (data) {
                            console.log("'Data' (id=" + cachedDataId + ") uploaded from cache.");
                            tx.executeSql('delete from [data] where [id] = ?', [cachedDataId],
                                function (tx, resultSet) {
                                    console.log("'[data] where [id]=" + cachedDataId + "' deleted.");
                                    app.uploadCachedData(tx);
                                },
                                function (error) {
                                    console.log("'" + error.message + "' deleting [data] where [id]=" + cachedDataId + "'.");
                                });
                        },
                        function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("'" + error.message + "' uploading Data (id=" + cachedDataId + ") from cache.");
                        });
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                console.error("'" + error.message + "' selecting '[data]'.");
            });

    }

};

app.initialize();
```

When the code runs, I see messages up to and including "'Data' (id=1) uploaded from cache", and the first row of data is sent to the server. I see no more messages, not the success or fail messages from the delete that follows that message. I also see no more messages to indicate that the recursive call has been made (there are 4 rows in my test data) and no other data is sent to the server.

Can anybody explain why the delete never seems to complete?

Thanks.

Comment: So it never executes `tx.executeSql('delete from [data] where [id] = ?', [cachedDataId]....`? Like, at all? Are you sure [cachedDataID] is good?

Comment: @MBillau: I have to assume that the 'delete from ...' is never executed as (a) the row remains in the database and (b) I do not see either of the console messages from the success or error callbacks. I also have to assume that cachedDataId is good as it displays the correct value in the previous message ("'Data' (id=1) uploaded from cache").

Comment: Can you put some console statements inside `executeSql` so we can see why it doesn't like that `delete` statement?

Comment: I cannot add any console statements as "executeSql" is provided by the browser running the JavaScript (in this case, I am testing it in Safari (UIWebView) on iOS as it is part of a Cordova based mobile application).

Answer (score 0):

I still have not found a reason for this. I have to assume that it is something to do with the fact that I am trying to perform the delete on the same transaction as the previous select.

By creating a new app.db.transaction and calling executeSql from that new transaction I was able to have the code run.

I would still be interested if anybody has a better solution.